# How to Iterate uploaded image files

Tags: php, arrays, loops, zend-framework, image-uploading

I want to use `foreach()` to move image files into a folder and print imageupload name, tmp_name and so on.  I am working on zend.

Input array:

```
 Array
(
    [imageUpload] => Array
        (
            [name] => P_20170224_134956_BF.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpBCB0.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1057039
        )

    [imageUpload1] => Array
        (
            [name] => P_20170308_135054_BF.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpBCD0.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1365444
        )

    [imageUpload2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Code:

```
$data = array_merge_recursive(
    $request->getPost()->toArray(),
    $request->getFiles()->toArray()
);
// echo'<pre>';print_r($data); 

$array = array_slice($data, 2);  
print_r($array); 
foreach($array as $files)
{ 
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        print_r($files); 
        $destination  = "public/img/".$file['name']; 
        $file_name    = $file['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($file_name,$destination);
        $data = __DIR__.('/../../../../../public/img/').$file['name'];
    }
}
```

`print_r()` with error:

```
 Array
    (
        [name] => P_20170224_134956_BF.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpBCB0.tmp
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 1057039
    )
    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'name' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\3Dklik\module\Photos\src\Photos\Controller\PhotosController.php</b> on line <b>84</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'tmp_name' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\3Dklik\module\Photos\src\Photos\Controller\PhotosController.php</b> on line <b>85</b><br />
    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'name' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\3Dklik\module\Photos\src\Photos\Controller\PhotosController.php</b> on line <b>87</b><br />
    Array
    (
        [name] => P_20170224_134956_BF.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpBCB0.tmp
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 1057039
    )
```

Comment: remove the inside foreach

Comment: Illegal string offset 'name'  ..i want a solution for that

Comment: after removing it i am unable to move my image file in folder @ jyothi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not have two foreach for this scenario. Your `$files` is an associative array:

```
foreach($array as $files)
{ 
    $destination  = "public/img/".$files['name']; 
    $file_name    = $files['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($file_name,$destination);
    $data = __DIR__.('/../../../../../public/img/').$files['name'];
}
```

If you use foreach for `$files`, then it will still dig into your inner associative array, where you cannot use key.

Comment: It is working but                                                                   
     $data = __DIR__.('/../../../../../public/img/').$files['name'];

  return new JsonModel(array(
        'data' => $data               It is not returing the file name

Comment: I was trying to tick the answer ..Because of internet issue it was not..So pllease don't disturb me...Better provide solution @mickmackusa

Comment: $data which i have put in json model is not showing me $files['name']. and in ajax sucess it is providing "Object "Please provide me solution @Thamilan

Comment: @piyuu `$data` is going to keep getting overwritten during each iteration.  `move_upload_file()` works because it is completely handled within the loop.  What ever you want to do to `$data` you need to do inside the loop.

Comment: By replacing $data with $data[] .I got my desired result